# What is/how do I use HFont in C#

Tags: c#, printing, pinvoke

I'm working with a printer SDK for a label printer in C#, details of which can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083309/getting-a-printer-api-to-work-with-c-sharp

Taking the advice given there, I used PInvoke to get the functions in the DLLs to work, and to my surprise, it all has began to come together...mostly.

A function SlpDrawTextXY() is supposed to be able to take an argument for a font of the type Hfont.  This can be created by a function called SlpCreateFont(). (details of these methods on pages 21 and 19 respectively of the documentation).

Now, my quest to discover what Hfont actually is has went poorly.  MSDN mentions it a bit, but doesn't really tell me what it is exactly.  The articles provided aren't really useful if you are going in blind and are definitely more suited to someone who is already half way there.  Other documentation about it is really slim and I'm left guessing at what the hell is supposed to be happening.

I have a block of code that looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpDebugMode(int nMode);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern int SlpOpenPrinter(String strPrinterName, int nID, bool fPortrait);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpClosePrinter();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern bool SlpStartLabel();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpDrawTextXY(int x, int y, Font iFont, String lpText);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern bool SlpEndLabel();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern Font SlpCreateFont(String lpName, int nPoints, int nAttributes);

    [DllImport("GDI32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr objectHandle); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 12);
        //IntPtr hFont = myFont.ToHfont();

        SlpDebugMode(2);

        SlpOpenPrinter("Smart Label Printer 440", 1, false);

        {
            SlpStartLabel();

            //Font font = SlpCreateFont("Courier", 12, 0);
            SlpDrawTextXY(30, 30, null, "Hello World!");

            SlpEndLabel();
        }

        SlpClosePrinter();
    }
}
```

There are some remnants of my toying around that have been commented out.  If it's commented out, it doesn't work.

This code will actually go to the printer and will 'print' a blank label, so it does seem like I'm really close.  The third argument in SlpDrawTextXY is where the font is supposed to be though and I have it set as 'null' just to see if I can get past it successfully.  This code is based on the sample C code in the documentation on page 12.  I would like to be able to transform this code into something that actually prints text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
static extern Font SlpCreateFont(...)
```

Using `Font` is not correct here.  SlpCreateFont() returns a HFONT, a "handle to font".  It is the way you manipulate a font when you create one in unmanaged code.  And is the exact same kind of animal you get back from the [Font.ToHfont()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.tohfont.aspx) method.  So you must declare it the way ToHfont() returns it, it must be `IntPtr` in your declarations.  Update the other declarations accordingly.

Do note that you'll have some decent odds that you can use Font.ToHfont() instead of SlpCreateFont().  The rules are the same however, you **must** be sure to call DeleteObject() when you are done using the font or you'll leak GDI objects that eventually will crash your code.

Comment: I forgot to thank you proper for this advice.  It saved me a ton of time and the solution works beautifully.  For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, I'll include the working code I have below in a separate response.

Answer (score 0):

Hans was absolutely right.  For future reference, below is working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SSLP
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpDebugMode(int nMode);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern int SlpOpenPrinter(String strPrinterName, int nID, bool fPortrait);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpClosePrinter();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern bool SlpStartLabel();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern void SlpDrawTextXY(int x, int y, IntPtr iFont, String lpText);

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern bool SlpEndLabel();

    [DllImport("SlpApi7x32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SlpCreateFont(String lpName, int nPoints, int nAttributes);

    [DllImport("GDI32.dll")]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr objectHandle); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        IntPtr font = SlpCreateFont("Arial", 10, 0);

        SlpDebugMode(2);

        //The second parameter defines the type of label per the documentation.
        SlpOpenPrinter("Smart Label Printer 440", 3, false);

        {
            SlpStartLabel();

            //Draw as much as you want with these!
            SlpDrawTextXY(0, 0, font, "Hello World");

            SlpEndLabel();
        }

        SlpClosePrinter();

        DeleteObject(font);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to put DeleteObject() in a finally block so you can be sure it will never leak.